# AWS EMR Presto not finding correct Hive schemas using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr, presto

So I am having an issue with being able to execute Presto queries via AWS EMR.

I have launched an EMR running hive/presto and using AWS Glue as the metastore.

When I SSH into the master node and run hive I can run "show schemas;" and it shows me the 3 different databases that we have on AWS Glue.

If I then enter the Presto CLI and run "show schemas on hive" I only see two "default" and "information_schema"

For the life of me I cannot figure out why presto is not able to see the same Hive schemas.

It is a basic default cluster launch on EMR using default settings mainly.

Can someone point me in the direction of what I should be looking for?  I have checked the hive.properties file and that looks good, I am just at a loss as to why presto is not able to see the same info as hive.

I do have the following configuration set

```
[{"classification":"hive-site", "properties":{"hive.metastore.client.factory.class":"com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"}, "configurations":[]}]
```

AWS docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-glue.html make it seem that this should be plug and play but I am obviously missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from **Amazon EMR release version 5.10.0** you can. Simply, set the hive.metastore.glue.datacatalog.enabled property to true, as follows:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "presto-connector-hive",
    "Properties": {
      "hive.metastore.glue.datacatalog.enabled": "true"
    }
  }
]
```

> Optionally, you can manually set
>   `hive.metastore.glue.datacatalog.enabled=true` in the
>   `/etc/presto/conf/catalog/hive.properties` file on the master node. If
>   you use this method, make sure that
>   `hive.table-statistics-enabled=false` in the properties file is set
>   because the Data Catalog does not support Hive table and partition
>   statistics. If you change the value on a long-running cluster to
>   switch metastores, you must restart the Presto server on the master
>   node (`sudo restart presto-server`).

**Sources**:
[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-glue.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this has been solved in emr-5.10.  You want to add the following config:

```
{"Classification":"presto-connector-hive","Properties":{"hive.metastore.glue.datacatalog.enabled": "true"}}
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-glue.html

Answer (score 0):

The recent 0.198 release of Presto now supports AWS Glue as a metadata source.

> Add support for using AWS Glue as the metastore. Enable it by setting
>   the hive.metastore config property to glue.
>
> https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.198.html